# Repeating words in string class

Tags: c++, string, class, pointers, operator-overloading

So I have to write a string class, and I need help with reading from a file into a vector of string classes I've created. It somewhat works, as it reads from the file but it repeats the the word read in a few times depending on which word it's on.

```
// .h


/*Class description:
A string class. Various functions for the class.
String is passed into objects of the class. Reads
and writes to files.*/

#ifndef MYString12_H
#define MYString12_H

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class MYString12
{
public:
    MYString12();
    MYString12(const MYString12 & mstr);
    MYString12(const char* ptr);
    ~MYString12();
    MYString12& operator = (const MYString12& argStr);
    friend MYString12 operator + (const MYString12& str1, const MYString12& str2);
    char operator [] (int index);
    bool operator > (const MYString12& argStr2);
    bool operator < (const MYString12& argStr2);
    bool operator == (const MYString12& argStr);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& istr, MYString12& argStr);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& istr, MYString12& argStr);
    int length() const;
    int capacity()const;
    char at(int index);
    const char* c_str()const;
    static int getCurrentCount();
    static int getCreatedCount();

private:
    char* str;
    int cap = 20;
    int end;
    const int compareTo(const MYString12& argStr);
    static int currentCount;
    static int createdCount;
};
#endif
```

Here is class cpp file

```
    // MYString12.cpp



#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MYString12.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int MYString12::createdCount = 0;
int MYString12::currentCount = 0;

// default constructor
MYString12::MYString12()
{
    cap = 20;
    end = 0;
    str = new char[cap];
    str[end] = '\0';

    createdCount++;
    currentCount++;
}



 // copy constructor
MYString12::MYString12(const MYString12& mstr)
{
    this->end = mstr.end;
    this->cap = mstr.cap;
    this->str = new char[mstr.cap];

    while (end >= cap) {
        cap += 20;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        str[i] = mstr.str[i];
    }
    //mstr.str[end] = '\0';

    createdCount++;
    currentCount++;
}


// constructor with string passed in
MYString12::MYString12(const char* ptr)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (ptr[i] != '\0') {
        end++;
        i++;
    }

    while (end >= cap) {
        cap += 20;
    }

    str = new char[cap];

    for (int j = 0; j < end; j++) {
        str[j] = ptr[j];
    }

    createdCount++;
    currentCount++;
}

// destructor
MYString12::~MYString12()
{
    delete[] str;
    currentCount--;
}

    // overloaded assignment operator
GAString12& GAString12::operator = (const GAString12& mstr)
{
    if (this == &mstr) {
        return *this;
    }

    this->end = mstr.end;
    this->cap = mstr.cap;

    while (end >= cap) {
        cap += 20;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        str[i] = mstr.str[i];
    }
    //mstr.str[end] = '\0';

    return *this;
}

// overloaded concatanation operator
MYString12 operator + (const MYString12& str1, const MYString12& str2)
{
    int temp = str1.end + str2.end + 1;

    char tempArray[200];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < temp)
    {
        if (i < str1.end)
        {
            tempArray[i] = str1.str[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            tempArray[i] = str2.str[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    tempArray[i] = '\0';

    MYString12 concatenatedObj(tempArray);

    return concatenatedObj;
}

// overloaded index operator
char MYString12::operator [] (int index)
{
    return str[index];
}

// overloaded greater than operator
bool MYString12::operator > (const MYString12& argStr)
{
    if ((*this).compareTo(argStr) > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// overloaded less than operator
bool MYString12::operator < (const MYString12& argStr)
{
    if ((*this).compareTo(argStr) < 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// overloaded equals equals operator
bool MYString12::operator == (const MYString12& argStr)
{
    if ((*this).compareTo(argStr) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// compares ascii values of objStr and argStr
const int MYString12::compareTo(const MYString12& argStr)
{
    int asciiSubtraction = 0;
    int limit = 0;

    if (end <= argStr.end)
    {
        limit = end;
    }
    else {
        limit = argStr.end;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (i <= limit && (str[i] == argStr.str[i])) {
        i++;
    }

    asciiSubtraction = str[i] - argStr.str[i];

    return asciiSubtraction;
}

// overloaded extraction operator
istream& operator >> (istream& istr, MYString12& argStr)
{
    char temp[100];

    istr >> temp;

    argStr = GAString12(temp);

    return istr;
}

// overloaded insertion operator
ostream& operator << (ostream& ostr, MYString12& argStr)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (argStr.str[i] != '\0')
    {
        ostr << argStr.str;
        i++;
    }
    return ostr;
}

// returns size of passed in string
int MYString12::length() const
{
    return end;
}

// returns size of memory allocated 
int MYString12::capacity() const
{
    return cap;
}

// returns a char of string at passed index
char MYString12::at(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index > end) {
        return '\0';
    }
    else {
        return str[index];
    }
}

// returns passed in string as c string
const char* MYString12::c_str() const
{
    createdCount++;
    currentCount++;

    return str;
}

// returns the amount of alive instances of class
int MYString12::getCurrentCount()
{
    return currentCount;
}

// returns the amount of overall created instances of class
int MYString12::getCreatedCount()
{
    return createdCount;
}
```

And here is main

```
// main
int main()
{
    vector<MYString12> word(100);
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("infile3.txt");

    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "Error." << endl;
        exit(1);
        }

    int wordCount = 0;
        while (fin >> word[wordCount]) {
        cout << word[wordCount];
        system("pause");
        wordCount++;
    }

    word.resize(wordCount);
    fin.close();endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't print out to the console any of the words. Nothing is printed. Why doesn't it print?

Comment: `vector<MYString12>` -- This requires that your `MYString12` is safely copyable and assignable.   Before starting to write overloades for `>>`, you should ensure that the class actually works using the basic operations that a `vector` will perform on it.  Where is your copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor for the `MYString12` class?

Comment: I included the rest of the .cpp file and the .h to give you a better look.

Comment: Why do all of that code in `operator >>`?  All you need is 3 lines of code (if your functions actually work): `istr >> temp; argStr = MyString12(temp); return istr;`.  This requires that your copy constructor and assignment operators actually work correctly, but if they do, learn to reuse code you've already written and not duplicate code.  If they don't work, then `operator >>` just revealed that those functions are buggy.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Do I need to have str = new char[cap]; in the constructor with string passed in, if I am already have this line of code in the default constructor?

Comment: A constructor creates a brand new object.  So all of your constructors will have to allocated memory, since each object has to have its own memory area for the characters.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have changed the overloaded assignment operator and copy constructor to what I think is correct, but now instead of getting repeating words, nothing is printed. Also, I changed my extraction operator definition as you recommended.